# Swift how to import rsa key

Tags: swift, encryption, rsa, private-key

Now,I have a keypair pem already.

I want to import this keypair in my Swift,and use this keypair to encrypt

something or decrypt something i got from restclint

I see many paper is saying how to general keypair, but i have it already.

and what is kSecAttrApplicationTag mean?

plz help me

```
var dataPtr:Unmanaged<AnyObject>?
let query: [String:AnyObject] = [
kSecClass: kSecClassKey,
kSecAttrApplicationTag: "com.example.site.public",
kSecReturnData: kCFBooleanTrue
]
let qResult = SecItemCopyMatching(query, &dataPtr)
// error handling with `qResult` ...
let publicKeyData = dataPtr!.takeRetainedValue() as NSData
// convert to Base64 string
let base64PublicKey = publicKeyData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Swift-RSAUtils](https://github.com/btnguyen2k/swift-rsautils), it provides what you need. I cannot thank Thanh Ba Nguyen enough for his fantastic pioneer work in this field. Apple, shame on you for making developers' lives so miserable!

Basically, the story is this: you must load the keys in their DER or PEM format (and decode base64 in case of PEM), then strip some parts from it, then import the keys to the system's keyring. Once this is done you can fetch them from the keyring and use them. Unfortunately, Apple hasn't documented this, particularly for Swift. The only reference documentation I could find was [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/index.html), and be sure you click "both" not only "Swift" or you won't see much. Or forget about it and go with Swift-RSAUtils, the code is pretty much self-explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest explanation: when you store something in keychain, it has a unique key (for identifying purpose). kSecAttrApplicationTag: "com.example.site.public" means "hey, the unique key I use is 'com.example.site.public'"

Cheers,